# Converting Objective function Optimizer

Tags: python, matrix

I am using optimizer to do mean variance portfolio optimization. Here in my code my objective function is `M.objective('obj', ObjectiveSense.Maximize, Expr.sub(dot,Expr.mul(alpha,m)))`

but go the below error.

error: `unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'Expr`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a reformulation in the style of https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#maximizing-the-sharpe-ratio

Comment: @Alex_P It doesn't use any API. The link contains a mathematical formulation, the last one in that section you can of course implement in Fusion. It is a cone and some linear constraints.